# Website doesn't want to fit to content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a problem with my website. I'm creating site with parallax scrolling effect, every section on website has 1000px and it's working good, but I want to make the last section higher (want to make in height: auto).

This how it looks (So min-height: 1000px but after 1000px it's like another section (without bg etc.)):

[image: So min-height: 1000px but after 1000px its like another section (without bg etc.)]

Code:

HTML:

```
<section id="kontakt" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
  <article>
    <div class="pasek_suwakow" style="top: 290px;">
      <a href="#marki"><div class="suwak_gora"></div></a>
      <a href="#manifest"><div class="suwak"></div></a>
      <a href="#wspolpraca"><div class="suwak"></div></a>
      <a href="#realizacje"><div class="suwak"></div></a>
      <a href="#kontakt"><div class="suwak_dol_wybrane"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div id="lastsection">

    <div id="map">
      <div id="vmap"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="contactbox">
      <div id="contactleft">
        <div id="contacttext">
         Siedziba firmy:<br><br>NEBIOLO POLSKA sp. z o. o.<br><br>
         ul. Olszewskiego 20<br>25-663 Kielce<br>Polska<br><br>
         tel. +48 41 278 72 60<br>fax. +48 41 278 72 61<br>
         email. office@nebiolo.com.pl<br>www.nebiolo.com.pl
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="contactright">
        <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formularz">
          <label  for="name">Imię i nazwisko:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="formularz_name"/></br></br>
          <label  for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="formularz_email"/></br></br>
          <label  for="phone">Telefon kontaktowy:</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="formularz_phone"/></br></br>
          <label  for="enquiry">Treść zapytania:</label><textarea name="enquiry" cols="40" rows="5" id="formularz_text"></textarea></br></br>
          <input type="button" id="contact_button" class="przycisk" value="Wyślij" />
        </form>

        <div id="formularz_odpowiedz">

        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style ="clear:both"></div>

    <div id="distributors">Wybierz kraj aby pokazać dystrybutorów</div>

    <table class="listadeweloperow Sweden">
      <tr class="nazwakraju"><td>Szwecja</td></tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td><td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nazwakraju"><td>Szwecja 2</td></tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
    </table>  

    <table class="listadeweloperow Czech-Republic">
      <tr class="nazwakraju"><td>Polska</td></tr>
      <tr class="wpisdystry">
        <td><img src="images/mztlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td><img src="images/mzlogomini.png" alt="MZT"></td>
        <td>ECO SOLUTIONS SCANDINAVIA</td>
        <td>STALLARHOLMSVAGEN 49, 124 59 BANDHAGEN,</td>
        <td>STOCKHOLM, SWEDEN</td>
        <td>00 48 784 77 44 25,</td>
        <td>SE: + 46 760 572 551</td>
        <td><a href="http://ecocolutions.se/" style="color:#0072c2;">http://ecocolutions.se/</a></td>
        <td>support@ecosolutions.se</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#kontakt { 
    background: #e9e9e7; 
    min-height: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 1920px; 
    position: relative; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    overflow: visible;
}
```

I want to make higher this section, to fit all content. Already tried with clear both.

Comment: You need to clearfix it > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix

Comment: What css do you use ot position the table?